# Javascript File not working in symfony twig

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, twig

In my symfony project my css is well linked, but my javascript is not working and I can't find why. I guess something stupid I missed ...! I tried with the encore webpack at firt since I'm runninh Sass, but I gave up and switched to the classi src=""

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`
           and uncomment the following Encore helpers to start using Symfony UX #}
        {% block stylesheets %}
{#            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}#}
{#            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}#}
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/mercuryseriesflashy/css/flashy.css') }}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('./build/app.css') }}">
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
{#            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}#}
            <!-- Flashy depends on jQuery -->



        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    {% block navbar %} {% include 'inc/navbar.html.twig'%}{% endblock %}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="{{ asset('./build/app.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

// any CSS you import will output into a single css file (app.scss in this case)
import './styles/app.scss';

import './bootstrap';
// start the Stimulus application

const logoMenu = document.querySelector('.logoMenuImg');
const contItems = document.querySelector('.contItems');
const arrItems = document.querySelectorAll('.items');

console.log(logoMenu);
console.log(contItems);
console.log(arrItems);

console.log('arrItems');

alert('hello world');
```

Thank you for your help

p.s: in the inspector it's blank no erros

Comment: I would assume, that the html produced will probably be wrong and the js file not being loaded at all. (check the network tab for files/urls trying to be requested)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `encore_entry_script_tags` i assume you have add your JS file in your webpack configuration ?
I see you're using assetic, if you are in Symfony 4.4 and more, remove it, it's deprecated. Use Webpack encore.

```js
let Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
let CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
//let TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

Encore
  // directory where compiled assets will be stored
  .setOutputPath('public/build/')
  // public path used by the web server to access the output path
  .setPublicPath('/build')

  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
  .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
;
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And run with `npm run build` or `yarn encore <env>`
Look at documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html